# templateClassName <className> t; Cannot assign class to template class argument

Tags: c++, visual-c++

C++ noob here. I trying to create a student information program by implementing
a Linked-List class as its data structure.

LinkedList.h

```
#pragma once
#include <stdexcept>

template <typename T>
class LinkedList
{
private:
    struct Node
    {
        T elem;
        Node *prev;
        Node *next;
    };

    Node *header;
    Node *trailer;
    int size;

public:
    LinkedList()
    {
        header = new Node;
        trailer = new Node;
        header->next = trailer;
        trailer->prev = header;
    }

    ~LinkedList()
    {
        while (!isEmpty())
            removeFirst();
        delete header;
        delete trailer;
    }

    const int& n_elem() const
    {
        return size;
    }

    const bool isEmpty() const
    {
        return size == 0;
    }

    const T& getFirst() const
    {
        if (isEmpty())
            throw std::out_of_range("List is empty.");
        return header->next->elem;
    }

    const T& getLast() const
    {
        if (isEmpty())
            throw std::out_of_range("List is empty.");
        return trailer->prev->elem;
    }

    void addFirst(const T& item)
    {
        addBetween(item, header, header->next);
    }

    void addLast(const T& item)
    {
        addBetween(item, trailer->prev, trailer);
    }

    void addAt(int index, const T& item)
    {
        Node *node = header;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
            node = node->next;
        addBetween(item, node, node->next);
    }

    const T removeFirst()
    {
        if (isEmpty())
            throw std::out_of_range("List is empty.");
        return remove(header->next);
    }

    const T removeLast()
    {
        if (isEmpty())
            throw std::out_of_range("List is empty.");
        return remove(trailer->prev);
    }

    const T removeAt(int index)
    {
        if (isEmpty())
            throw std::out_of_range("List is empty.");
        Node *node = header;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
            node = node->next;
        return remove(node->next);
    }

    const T& itemAt(int index) const
    {
        if (isEmpty())
            throw std::out_of_range("List is empty.");
        Node *node = header;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
            node = node->next;
        return node->next->elem;
    }

protected:
    void addBetween(const T& item, Node *predecessor, Node *successor)
    {
        Node *newest = new Node;
        newest->prev = predecessor;
        newest->next = successor;
        predecessor->next = newest;
        successor->prev = newest;
        size++;
    }

    const T remove(Node *node)
    {
        Node *predecessor = node->prev;
        Node *successor = node->next;
        predecessor->next = successor;
        successor->prev = predecessor;
        T oldItem = node->elem;
        size--;
        delete node;
        return oldItem;
    }
};
```

Student class is defined below.

Program.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "LinkedList.h"

using namespace std;

class Student
{
public:
    string name;
    string id;
    int score;
    static const int total = 100;
    double grade;

    Student(string n, string i, int s)
    {
        name = n;
        id = i;
        score = s;
        grade = getGrade(score);
    }

private:
    double getGrade(int score)
    {
        return (23.0 / 3.0 - ((20.0 * score) / (3.0 * total)));
    }
};

LinkedList<Student> l;

int main()
{
    //Some code here
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know the reason why

```
LinkedList<Student> l;
```

produces an error:

```
LinkedList<Student>::Node::Node(void)': attempting to reference a deleted function
```

But when I use:

```
LinkedList<Student*> l;
```

there's no error.

Please help.
I'm using Visual Studio 2015.

And sorry for bad English.

Comment: Try moving your class definition before your link list import or putting the class in a .cpp and .h file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `LinkedList<Student>`, the inner struct `Node` looks like this:

```
struct Node
{
    Student elem;
    Node *prev;
    Node *next;
};
```

so every Node contains a Student.

However, you'll note that `Student` has a constructor that takes arguments:

```
Student(string n, string i, int s)
```

and it does not have a constructor that does not take arguments.

So if you were to write `new Node`, the computer would create a Node, and as part of that it would create a `Student`, but it can't do that because it doesn't have any arguments to give to `Student`'s constructor.

That's (approximately) what "deleted function" means here - normally the compiler would make a `Node` constructor for you, but in this case it can't.

And so `new Node` doesn't work, because `Node` doesn't have a constructor.

Probably the easiest fix here is just to give `Student` a no-argument constructor as well - something like:

```
Student()
{
    name = "";
    id = "";
    score = 0;
    grade = getGrade(score);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You explained it well.

Comment: The correct way would be to add to `Node` a constructor taking a `T`. And have `header` and `trailer` be `nullptr` and really point to expected node instead of `header->next`.